Applying a condition to a column in a table using If
Let's assume we have the code below (The below code is derived from answer @DanielHuber link and answer @Domen link)
Clear["Global`*"]
SeedRandom[1234];
Rz = 1 - (1 - Subscript[x, 1] Subscript[x, 2]) (1 - Subscript[x, 3]);
(data = Tuples[{0, 1}, 3]) // MatrixForm;
LL1 = {Block[{Subscript}, 
     Do[Subscript[x, j] = Transpose[data][[j]], {j, 3}]; 
     Rz]}/(Binomial[2, {data[[All, 1]] + data[[All, 3]]}] Binomial[
      1, {data[[All, 2]]}]);
old1 = (table = 
     Prepend[Transpose@
       Join[{Range@Length@data}, 
        Transpose@
         data, {data[[All, 1]] + data[[All, 3]]}, {data[[All, 2]]}, 
        LL1], Flatten[{"order", Subscript["x", #] & /@ Range[3], "l1",
         "l2", "H"}]]) // Grid[#, Frame -> All] &;
newtab1 = 
  old1 //. {s___, {x0_, x1_, x2_, x3_, l1_, l2_, H_}, 
     m___, {y0_, y1_, y2_, y3_, l1_, l2_, d_}, 
     e___} :> {s, {x0, x1, x2, x3, l1, l2, H + d}, m, e};
newtab2 = 
 First[newtab1] /. {data12 : 
      PatternSequence[order_?NumericQ, x1_, x2_, x3_, l1_, l2_, 
       H_], ___} :> 
    With[{h1 = If[l1 == 2, If[l1 - 1, 1, 0], "--"]}, {data12, h1}] // 
  Grid[#, Frame -> All] &


I have a problem in the last two cells in the last column. I want to put a condition as follows:
The condition: If H at (l1 , l2)  greater than  H at (l1 - 1, l2) take 1 either 0

Since H=1 at (2,0) > H=1/2 at (l1-1,0)=(1,0), then take 1
Since H=1 at (2,1) = H=1 at (l1-1,0)=(1,1), then take 0
Is it possible to put the condition above
I have tried a lot and did not reach a result
Please help. Thank you very much.

You have If[l1 - 1, 1, 0] right at the end. Did you mean If[l1 == 1, 1, 0]?

@march This is wrong because I did not reach a result. The problem lies in comparing the cells of a column based on the cells of the corresponding column: as an expression for the condition like this " If H at (l1 , l2) greater than H at (l1 - 1, l2) take 1 either 0". I did not reach a way to write it programmatically.

This is now your fourth question on the same underlying data structure/problem. Each question gets more complicated, because you don't explain what you are actually calculating, you just take the answer from the previous question, and then it doesn't work when you make things more complicated.
You are also not reaching a result, because the programming style of your code is bad. Instead of doing so much pure list manipulations, you should rely more on the symbolic approach. Let me try to rewrite your code in at least more readable style, even though this is difficult without knowing what is actually going on.
First, write down definitions of your quantities. You have there some kind of an index, for which I will use n.
Clear["Global`*"]
tuples = Tuples[{0, 1}, 3];

x[i_][n_] := tuples[[n]][[i]];
Rz[n_] := 1 - (1 - x[1][n] x[2][n]) (1 - x[3][n]);

l[1][n_] := x[1][n] + x[3][n];
l[2][n_] := x[2][n];

h0[n_] := Rz[n]/(Binomial[2, l[1][n]] Binomial[1, l[2][n]]);

z[n_] /; l[1][n] == 2 := If[h[l[1][n], l[2][n]] > h[l[1][n] - 1, l[2][n]], 1, 0];
z[__] = "--";

I hope you agree that this is more readable.
Now the tricky part. You are somehow combining some of your rows. I will do this via GatherBy to find groups of n where l[1] and l[2] are the same:
ns = GatherBy[Table[{n, l[1][n], l[2][n]}, {n, Length[tuples]}], Rest][[All, All, 1]]
(* {{1}, {2, 5}, {3}, {4, 7}, {6}, {8}} *)

I will now set your h by summing the appropriate h0. Note that I will do two different assignments: h[n], which allows you to get h by its index, and also h[l[1][n], l[2][n]], which allows you to get h by l[1] and l[2]:
With[{n = First[#]},
    h[n] = h[l[1][n], l[2][n]] = Sum[h0[i], {i, #}]
    ] & /@ ns;

Look at Definition[h] to see what happened in the code above.
Finally, you can generate your table:
headings = {{"order", "x1", "x2", "x3", "l1", "l2", "H"}};
data = Table[{n, x[1][n], x[2][n], x[3][n], l[1][n], l[2][n], h[n], z[n]}, {n, First /@ ns}];
Grid[headings~Join~data, Frame -> All]



Thank you so much for your valuable help. I apologize if my question is not appropriate. I'm not a specialist; I'm trying to connect some concepts to reach mathematical results and verify them in my study. I'm sorry, but I will explain the upcoming questions in detail. Thanks again for your help; it means a lot to me.

@Emadkareem, no need to apologize, I just wanted to give you some feedback :)
